# Could someone help me understand the connection between these two wikipedia entries? (reciprocal lattice)

Tags: definition, fourier-transform, crystals, lattice-model

1. The [Brillouin zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone) is a primitive cell (more specifically a Wigner-Seitz cell) of the reciprocal lattice, which plays an important role in solid state physics due to Bloch's theorem.
2. A [Wigner–Seitz cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Seitz_cell), like any primitive cell, is a fundamental domain for the discrete translation symmetry of the lattice. The primitive cell of the reciprocal lattice in momentum space is called the Brillouin zone.

I am trying to understand how Brillouin zone, primitive cell and reciprocal lattice are connected. I have copy pasted two sentences from wikipedia I believe are "key" to understanding this, but can't wrap my head around what they mean. What is meant by primitive cell? - and why does it matter that the Brillouin zone is a primitive cell of the reciprocal lattice?

Answer (score 2):

First, let's define all of them:

*Primitive cell* : A primitive unit cell for a periodic crystal is a unit cell containing exactly one lattice point.

*Wigner-Seitz cell* : Given a lattice point the set of all points in space that are closer to that given point than to any other lattice point that constitutes the Wigner-Seitz cell of the given lattice point.

*Brillouin zone* A Brillouin zone is any primitive unit cell of the reciprocal lattice.

---

Let's see the connection in brief:

First, It's always true that the Wigner-Seitz construction for a lattice gives a primitive unit cell. The primitive unit cell contains exactly one lattice point and this sometimes makes counting much easier.

As Brillouin zone is a primitive unit cell of the reciprocal lattice, its construction is similar to Wigner-Seitz's construction for the direct lattice.

---

P.S. : It's always better to go through a textbook rather than wondering in Wikipedia.